# Percentage plot of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1100,1200,1620], 
                    [60,4880,7950],
                    [1100,6878,11564], 
                    [430,15100,52765],
                    [0,6150,63990]],
              columns=['A', 'B', 'Total'],
             index = ['ITEM1', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM3', 'ITEM4', 'ITEM5'])

df.plot.bar()
```

How can I create a plot, but using the percentages on each ITEM_, columns?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right and I cannot comment. Do you mean like this?

```
df.T.plot.bar()
```

I just transposed the dataframe for the plot.

[image: Bar chart]

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1100,1200,1620], 
                    [60,4880,7950],
                    [1100,6878,11564], 
                    [430,15100,52765],
                    [0,6150,63990]],
              columns=['A', 'B', 'Total'],
             index = ['ITEM1', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM3', 'ITEM4', 'ITEM5'])
df['percA'] = df['A']/df['Total']*100
df['percB'] = df['B']/df['Total']*100
df[['percA', 'percB']].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1100, 1200, 1620],
                            [60, 4880, 7950],
                            [1100, 6878, 11564],
                            [430, 15100, 52765],
                            [0, 6150, 63990]],
                      columns=['A', 'B', 'Total'],
                      index=['ITEM1', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM3', 'ITEM4', 'ITEM5'])
    df_col_percent = 100*df /df.sum(0)
    df_item_percent = 100*df.T/df.sum(1)
    df_item_percent.plot(kind='bar')
    df_col_percent.plot(kind='bar')
```

Will plot the correct percentage (other solutions here assumed Total = A + B), I'm in a hurry so won't add plots, tudulu